# Find and retrieve six digits from a string varchar - SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to extract a six digit number from a varchar column. The six digits appear in a unstructured matter in the column. See example below.

> **Col1**
>
> 1018477-0001 WhytoOne
>
> DK 1-Sam-2011 EasttoVest 101846-0001
>
> WhytoOne 1018477-0001

Comment: please be a bit more elaborate. post what you want and how do you wish to achieve it and what you have done so far and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `PATINDEX` function, providing it with the pattern:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( Col1 VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1018477-0001 WhytoOne' ),
        ( 'DK 1-Sam-2011 EasttoVest 101846-0001' ),
        ( 'WhytoOne 1018477-0001' )


SELECT *, 
       SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col1), 6) ,
       SUBSTRING(Col1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col1), 
                       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Col1, 
                                                      PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col1), 
                                                      LEN(Col1))) - 1)
FROM @t
```

Output:

```
1018477-0001 WhytoOne                    101847 1018477
DK 1-Sam-2011 EasttoVest 101846-0001     101846 101846
WhytoOne 1018477-0001                    101847 1018477
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 declare @t table (Col nvarchar(1000))
 insert into @t
         ( Col)
 values  ( '1018477-0001 WhytoOne')
        ,( 'DK 1-Sam-2011 EasttoVest 101846-0001')
        ,( 'WhytoOne 1018477-0001')

SELECT *, 
       right(SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col), 6),1) as [SixthNumber]
       ,SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col), 6) as [FirstSixNumbers]
       ,substring(Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col), 
                       PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Col, 
                                                      PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Col), 
                                                      LEN(Col))) - 1) as [AllNumbers]
FROM @t
```